# Where is qtRunLoggedCommand defined?

Tags: qt, qmake

I often see the calling of qtRunLoggedCommand in Qt project files but cannot find where it is defined. Can anybody provide a link to the document of this function or let me know where the function is defined in the source code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is defined in [qtbase/mkspecs/features/configure_base.prf](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/mkspecs/features/configure_base.prf#n51):

```
defineTest(qtRunLoggedCommand) {
    qtLog("+ $$1")

    !equals(3, false): \
        1 = "( $$1 ) 2>&1"
    output = $$system("$$1", lines, result)
    lg =
    for (l, output): \
        lg += "> $$l"
    qtLog($$lg)
    !isEmpty(2) {
        $$2 = $$output
        export($$2)
    }

    !equals(result, 0): return(false)
    return(true)
}
```